# Merge results from two datasets in mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. I want to retrieve `column1` from `table1` and `column1` from `table2`. Then combine these two results and display in the grid view as separate columns. Here's my code:

```
string query4 = "select tablename from table1 where tid='1'";
MySqlCommand command4 = new MySqlCommand(query4, connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.SelectCommand = command4;
adapter.Fill(ds);

GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
string query5 = "select fname from table2 where id='1'";
MysqlCommand command5 = new MySqlCommand(query5, connection);

DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
adapter.SelectCommand = command5;
adapter.fill(ds2);

Gridview1.DataSource = ds;
```

This gives me only `table1` value, but I want to display both columns from `table1` and `table2` in single grid view.

Comment: Do you mean columns or rows?  Only the UNION response below relate to having them returned as 2 rows with 1 column.  My response (JOIN) relates to having them returned as 1 row with 2 columns.  I am not sure what Kevin's answer would give you though

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on MSDN brings up the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/803bh6bc.aspx

Use the `DataSet.Merge()` method.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html INNER JOIN is your friend,

```
SELECT
    table1.tablename, 
    table2.fname 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.id = table1.tid 
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

This will get all the data in one query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two approach. 1st is from MySQL query like this:

```
string query6 = "select tablename AS value from table1 where tid='1' UNION select fname from table2 as value where id='1'";
```

or combine your `DataSets` in one `DataSet` using `DataSet.Merge();`